# TypeError: (intermediate value).map is not a function when using set for Country Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, select, set

I am building a React app that is requesting data from an an Api.  Now as part of the application I want to filter by Regions of the Api.  Now I realise that I need to use Sets to extract just the regions.   Below is the code that I have so far:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CountryList } from './Components/Card-List/CountryList';
import { SearchBox } from './Components/Search-box/Search-Box';
import { NavBarCard }from './Components/NavBar/NavBarCard';
import './Countries.styles.css';


class Countries extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        countries:[],
        searchField:"",
        regionField:"",
        darkMode: false
    }
    this.setDarkMode = this.setDarkMode.bind(this);
    this.handleRegion = this.handleRegion.bind(this);
};


componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(all =>  this.setState({ countries: all,
        regions: all}))
}


setDarkMode(e){
    this.setState((prevState) => ({ darkMode: !prevState.darkMode }));
}

handleRegion(e){
    this.setState({regionField: e.target.value})
}
render() {
    const { countries, searchField, regionField, darkMode } = this.state;
    const filterCountries = countries.filter((country) => country.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchField.toLowerCase()) &&
     country.region.toLowerCase().includes(regionField.toLowerCase()));

     return(


            <div className={darkMode ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode" }>

                 <NavBarCard handlechange={this.setDarkMode} moonMode={darkMode ? "moon fas fa-moon" : "moon far fa-moon"} darkMode={darkMode ? "dark-mode" : "light-mode"}/>


                <div className="Input">

                    < SearchBox type="search" placeholder="Search a Country" handlechange={e=> this.setState({
                        searchField: e.target.value })}
                        />


                        <select onChange={this.handleRegion} value={regionField}>
                            {new Set(countries.map(country=>country.region))
                            .map(uniqueRegion => 
                            <option>{uniqueRegion}</option>)}
                        </select>
                </div>
                <CountryList countries={filterCountries} />

            </div>

         )
       }
     }

   export default Countries;
```

The error I am getting is `TypeError: (intermediate value).map is not a function` for the Select tag. Not sure what I missed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function called map defined over the set so you need to create an array out of it first. To do that you can make use of `Array.from` on the result of `new Set`

```
 <select onChange={this.handleRegion} value={regionField}>
                        {Array.from(new Set(countries.map(country=>country.region)))
                        .map(uniqueRegion => 
                        <option>{uniqueRegion}</option>)}
                    </select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to iterate over Set, Sets do not expose .map method. You should convert the set back to Array before iterating.
Please try this and see if it works.

```js
<select onChange={this.handleRegion} value={regionField}>
{Array.from(new Set(countries.map(country=>country.region)))
.map(uniqueRegion => 
<option>{uniqueRegion}</option>)}
</select>
```